# How to do core update with drush

Tags: drush, updating

With which drush command can I update my Drupal 7.36 to 7.41?

I have tried so far the followings:

- drush up drupal
- drush pm-updatecode

But nothings has changed in either the code nor when I look at the currently pending updates.

Answer (score 0):

Adi provided a good answer. So update the code with:

```
drush up drupal
```

But after that always preform database updates (if required):

```
drush updb
```

Answer (score 0):

`drush upc`
should update all modules and core